# Send mail to multiple receiver with HTML mailto

Tags: html, mailto

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Emailing to multiple recipients with HTML Mailto: not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278363/emailing-to-multiple-recipients-with-html-mailto-not-working)

I want to send with 1 HTML link a mail to multiple (100) recievers...

```
<a href="mailto:first@mail.example; second@mail.example; third@mail.example">Send</a>
```

This link doesn't work. It do nothing when  I press the link.

Comment: Use comma instead of semicolon?

Comment: @CyberDude: also with comma it don't work. There are about 100 mails...

Comment: @user1671245 does it work with one?

Comment: might be good candidate to go for distribution list / email groups. Just a thought.

Comment: I have a similar situation. The mailto: I have is being populated by a member database, nearly 100 people. 

The mailto link exists to allow all members, create a mass email to reach all members. 

If we are unable to use mailto for this quantity of members, is different method to deliver the same result?

Comment: You can set each and every part of an email. Here's a tool I built to make it dead simple: https://mailto.now.sh. You'll want to make use of everyone else's advice of the "," to delimit multiple recipients 

Answer (score 91):

> "There are no safe means of assigning multiple recipients to a single
> mailto: link via HTML. There are safe, non-HTML, ways of assigning
> multiple recipients from a mailto: link."

[http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/www_faq/multrec.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20151116223616/http://www.sightspecific.com/%7Emosh/WWW_FAQ/multrec.html)

For a quick fix to your problem, change your `;` to a comma `,` and eliminate the spaces between email addresses

```
<a href='mailto:person1@domain.example,person2@domain.example'>Email Us</a>
```

Comment: also with comma it don't work. There are about 100 mails...

Comment: @user1671245 This appears to be client specific. Using semi colons works for me using IE and Outlook.

Comment: RFC 6068 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6068) has this definition of the `to` field: `to           = addr-spec *("," addr-spec )`. I understand this as a way of defining multiple recipients, separated by a comma.

Comment: Be careful with this, as ; does not work on mac.

Comment: should work in Outlook

Comment: I have 2 cases where using ; causes mac mail client to stop working, and ending in an endless loop where it is trying to send to and invalid mail address. Which caused the mail provider to mark their account as being spam. DO NOT USE is my recommendation.

Comment: To try and gather some data, try the example link here, and report back your email client and if it succeeds or fails to add multiple emails: https://codepen.io/jesstelford/pen/zeKgdg?editors=1000

Comment: Gmail on Android works successfully using commas.

Comment: Apple Mail on OSX works successfully using commas.

Comment: It works fine using commas, Thunderbird on Ubuntu.

Comment: doesn't work with my outlook