# Foreach loop inside a href?

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

I'm wondering if it's possible to put a foreach loop inside a href?

The reason is because I want a link to be able to link to multiple emails and I don't know how to do it otherwise.

I'm using HTML, Razor

I tried doing like this:

```
 @foreach (var syv in syvs)
            {
               <a href="mailto:@syv.ePost" target="_top">@syv.ePost</a>

            }
```

But now it displays all the mails. What I want is one link that mails to all.

I need something that only loops the mails **inside** the link, but I can't figure out how. I want to send email to multiple people when clicked.

Comment: what language are you using? PHP? please show what you have done.

Comment: can you explain what you mean you want to link to multiple emails? send email to different person when clicked or send different emails to the same person when clicked?

Comment: @cweitat I mean send email to different people when clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [send mail to multiple receiver with HTML mailto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765286/send-mail-to-multiple-receiver-with-html-mailto)

Comment: @CodeCaster it's not a duplicate because I'm working with razor. Stop judging my post just because it has a negative score. Thank you

Comment: It absolutely is. Your question is actually two questions: _"Can I use multiple addresses in an `<a href="mailto:"`"_, which is [answered in the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765286/send-mail-to-multiple-receiver-with-html-mailto). Then, after reading that one, your other question is _"How can I create one semicolon-separated string from multiple strings"_, which has been answered thousands of times before. You don't _need_ a loop for that; a simple `@string.Join(";", syvs.Select(s => s.ePost))` will do. Do your research and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

**I'm not familiar with this language, but you could try something like :**

```
<a href="mailto: @foreach (var syv in syvs) { @syv.ePost }"target="_top">Link to all the mail</a>
```

Note that I don't know the syntax you are using, I'm just showing the logic here : looping on the href attribute. You'll need to separate each email address with a comma.

Comment: Thank you, it's working. Do you happen to know how to add a space between each mail?

Comment: For more information : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16106196/concatenating-strings-in-razor

Comment: But yeah, this is for sure laziness :)