# How to Create a Mailto Share Button that Opens a Window in which Ones Can Enter Email Address to Send to

Tags: javascript, mailto, window.open

I've been searching all over the internet to find out how to create a `mailto` share button that opens up a new window in which the user can then type in the email address of his choice to send to. I've an attached a sequential set of images as operational example:

What is the trick to this? Why can't I find any info on how to write such code ....absolutely nowhere on Stack Overflow either!

As of right now this is the code that I have:

```
 $('.share-page-on-Email').click(function() {
  window.open("mailto:"+emailTo+'?cc='+emailCC+'&subject='+emailSub+'&body='+emailBody, '_self');
   });
```

View my prototype Email share button at my Code Pen here: https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/rpdBQJ/

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @guest271314, nothing happens.

Comment: "nothing happens" does not answer what is expected to happen. What is the requirement?

Comment: I want the result to be the image above, that's the result I want to eventually get.

Comment: What do you mean? Is solely creating the form the eventual expected result? Are you not expecting a native system email application to be launched? Have you coded the web-based email application already which handles `mailto:`? What  do you expect to occur when the visitor presses "Send"?

Comment: If you just put in a mailto link as `<a href="mailto:">Send Mail</a>` or `<a href="mailto:?subject=Help">Get Help</a>` it will pop open the user's preferred native mail program with no `To:` address pre-set. If you want what you've pictured, well that's not what a `mailto:` does -- that is a form that you would create yourself and, when it's submitted, create an email on the back-end. Creating and sending an email on the server would depend on what tech stack you're using on the server.

Comment: @StephenP, ok thankyou! That's what I need to hear. Thankyou for you time!

Comment: @guest271314, see edits in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend never using that mailto: feature as it behaves unpredictably, different on different devices and sometimes fails alltogether. You could create a page just to take the email string then do whatever you want with it server side. Make the popup/popover small like:

```
<a href="/my-email-collector-page"
   onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow',
                                   'toolbar=no,
                                    location=no,
                                    status=no,
                                    menubar=no,
                                    scrollbars=yes,
                                    resizable=yes,
                                    width=200px,
                                    height=120px');
 return false;">email</a>
```

Comment: OMG! Thanks for this!!

Comment: When I combine this code with the rest of my code on my JavaScript page at CodePen([https://codepen.io/IDCoder/full/rpdBQJ/]), those codes stop working. Why is that? Also, is there a way to, instead of having `<a href="/my-email-collector-page"
   onclick="window.open`, I can have something like this: `$('.class name here').click(function() { window.open(other code here});` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use window.location.href like this:

`window.location.href = 'mailto:email@domain.com'`

Comment: where in my code do I put `window.location.href = 'mailto:email@domain.com'` ?

Comment: Wouldn't this open a new browser window, followed by launching the user's native email program? Then you'd have an empty browser window to close. Curious; I haven't tried it. (Just tried it... nope, it just opens the mail client. but then, why this and not a plain `<a href="mailto:email@domain.com">` link?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `navigator.registerProtocolHandler()` to set specific domains to handle specific protocols as demonstrated by @PaulIrish at [Getting Gmail to handle all mailto: links with registerProtocolHandler](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/Getting-Gmail-to-handle-all-mailto-links-with-registerProtocolHandler).

[`.registerProtocolHandler()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/system-state.html#dom-navigator-registerprotocolhandler) must be called at the origin where the protocol is to be handled by the web application, else an error occurs.

> User agents must throw a ["SecurityError"](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#securityerror) DOMException if the
>   [resulting URL record](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/urls-and-fetching.html#resulting-url-record) has an [origin](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-url-origin) that differs from the
>   origin specified by the relevant settings object of this
>   NavigatorContentUtils object.

For example, you can navigate to "https ://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox", then at `console`

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto",
                                  "https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s",
                                  "Gmail");

var email = `<a href="mailto:yourbestfriend@example.com?subject=registerProtocolHandler()%20FTW!&amp;body=Check%20out%20what%20I%20learned%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Fupdates.html5rocks.com%2F2012%2F02%2FGetting-Gmail-to-handle-all-mailto-links-with-registerProtocolHandler%0A%0APlus%2C%20flawless%20handling%20of%20the%20subject%20and%20body%20parameters.%20Bonus%20from%20RFC%202368!" target="_blank">this mailto: link</a>`;

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", email);

document.body.querySelector("a[href^=mailto]:nth-last-of-type(1)").click();
```

which should launch a `window` having title "Compose Mail", with Subject and Body populated.

To include "cc" you can place

```
cc=email@domain.com&amp;
```

within the string following last

```
&amp;
```

on the

```
?subject=
```

line, see [mailto with multiple cc addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26509787/mailto-with-multiple-cc-addresses).

Or write the service for your own online email application to achieve the same handling of requests for specific protocols.