# JavaScript to a href troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

Basically I want to create a link that pulls data from 2 different txt files on my server.. lets say #addr and #price

I want my link to look something like..

```
"bitcoin:' + addr + '?amount=' + price"
```

Example...

```
bitcoin:1MgsAHrjke9r769sH5pZdWoC1CcYXZY6oT?amount=0.000456
```

I have this code pulling the price and addr..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#price").load('http://xxxxx.com/price.txt');


});
</script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#addr").load('http://xxxxx.com/addr.txt');


});
</script>
```

EDIT: Using working code in answer:

Last thing i can't figure out.. how to get...

```
"<a href='bitcoin:" + $("#addr").text() + "?amount=" + $("#price").text() + "'>TEXTHERE</a>";
```

to only show the #addr data where TEXTHERE is.. apparently i'm terrible at structuring these links.

Code seems to work at pulling my correct data strings.. just have no clue how to make a working link!

Anyone help? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just concatenate the values you placed into the elements. But, you have to wait for the two **[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** calls to complete before you can use the values returned from the AJAX calls that they make. To ensure that you don't act before the results come back, you pass a function as the second argument to `.load()` that should be called when the call is complete. After the first call, we pass a function that makes the second call and to that second call, we pass a function that completes the operation.

Also, there's no need for two scripts and two `document.load` callbacks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // You need to wait for the .load calls to complete before you can use the results
  $("#price").load('http://xxxxx.com/price.txt', function(){
    $("#addr").load('http://xxxxx.com/addr.txt', function(){
  
      var link = 
       "<a href='bitcoin:" + $("#addr").text() + "?amount=" + $("#price").text() + "'>" + $("#addr").text() + "</a>";

       // And then append the link where you need it:
       $(document.body).append(link); 
       console.log($("a")[0].href);
 
    });
  });
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="price">67.54</div>
<div id="addr">123welkjwekj133131@#232</div>
```

But, as @guest271314 points out, the `:bitcoin` protocol portion of that `href` may not be recognized by the client, so you will need to let the browser know what it means and how to use it by calling: [`navigator.registerProtocolHandler()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/system-state.html#dom-navigator-registerprotocolhandler) prior to the code I've shown.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response Scott. No link shows up when I copy that code (and replace the links obviously). I should have mentioned in my original post I want the link to show up as the #addr text. I will also look into the navigator protocol. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @largeanincharge If you are building the entire `a` element, then you need to use the `.append()` method to get the HTML string parsed and a new element created. If you have a pre-existing `a` element, we can just update the `href` attribute on it with the new string value. So, changing the `#addr` element's text alone won't do it. Also, check your Console tab of your Developer's Tools to make sure you don't have any other errors.

Comment: @largeanincharge I have updated my answer and fixed a typo.

Comment: @guest271314 Ah yes. I was focused on the link construction. ;)

Comment: @The code can be located anywhere you like (in the `head` or at the end of the `body` is fine). Because of the `document.ready()`, the code won't run until the entire HTML contents have been read.

Comment: Soo l have the price and addr data still loading the divs correctly with your code, however i still can't get a clickable link to show up for the life of me.

Comment: My HTML is statically loaded with sample data because I can't make the `.load()` calls work here in this environment. Don't use my HTML. I'm afraid I can't be of more assistance without seeing all your code. Can you update your question to include all the relevant code?

Comment: Got everything working perfectly now. Thank you soo much. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @largeanincharge Please mark my answer as "the" answer and up vote as well.

Comment: Done! Also updated the original question with one more little problem i'm having ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`navigator.registerProtocolHandler()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/system-state.html#dom-navigator-registerprotocolhandler) to register the `bitcoin:` protocol at a specific origin, see [How to Create a Mailto Share Button that Opens a Window in which Ones Can Enter Email Address to Send to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431386/how-to-create-a-mailto-share-button-that-opens-a-window-in-which-ones-can-enter/48432204#48432204).

Comment: Sorry to sound ignorant but I have no clue what that means or how to implement that. I usually do pretty okay with html from just googling my problems but this one has been bugging me for quite some time with none of my efforts fixing it.

Comment: @largeanincharge Have you read the lined Question and answers?
 See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler

Comment: Will look more into that once I can get the darn link to even show up! lol