# Compose multiple mails from single mailto option

Tags: php, email, mailto

I am new to PHP, I want to send emails to multiple recipients but from same mail client using mailto option in php
for example I have an array containing email addresses.
I tried this:

```
$recipients = array(
  "youremailaddress@yourdomain.com", 
  "youremailaddress2@yourdomain.com",

);
$email_to = implode(',', $recipients);  
$body = "Body";
```

But this will add all recipients on same email. I need to create separate Draft  for all receivers and I want only one receiver in one draft. I can't use BCC. Can anyone help me out for creating mails using:

```
 "<a href='mailto:".$email_to."?body=".$body."' target='_top'> </a>"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emailing to multiple recipients with html Mailto: not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278363/emailing-to-multiple-recipients-with-html-mailto-not-working)

Comment: The accepted answer there has given the answer for the first part of the question asked there but not the solution for composing different emails within same mail client.

Comment: Actually... if you mean like creating lots of **different** `<a>` tags one after the other, each one having a mailto recipient and all having the same body (or could be different too, depending on how you code it), you can use the function `foreach`, so you won't have to `implode` your array. I can show you how to do it but first let me know if that's what you need.

Comment: Well, I don't really have time now, but if that's it maybe someone else can put it up or I will in like... 8 hours or so.

Comment: I tried doing the same, I got an exception that I could only open one instance of  Thunderbird on the second iteration.

Comment: @zeke: I will be eagerly waiting for your response, if no one shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, supposing that what I commented was what you were looking for, I would do the following (you can edit it to just echo the whole thing):

```
$body = "Body";
$recipients = array(
    "youremailaddress@yourdomain.com", 
    "youremailaddress2@yourdomain.com",
);
foreach($recipients as $v){
    $a_tags .= '<a href="mailto:'.$v.'?body='.$body.'" target="_top"> </a>';
}
```

Note that I'm using `.=` so I can concatenate all the `<a>` tags, you can later output your `$a_tags` variable wherever you want.

Comment: If you get that exception again (which I don't see why you would get it), let me know and update your question with the report you got so I can check it out. Maybe this isn't the right approach for your project, but I don't know since I don't even know about it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution,  with slight changes on your answer it worked out. :)

Comment: Alright, feel free to edit my answer to show the real solution! I'm glad I could help!