# Up to how many emails can i send with mailto?

Tags: node.js, mailto

I have chatbot that copies an email list from google sheets, the list is 300 mails exactly, the problem is that it doesn't work with that many emails, i tried different formats of joining the email list using " , " and " ; " but it won't work either way.

To try to fix this issue i used the copy function from javascript but chrome made an update and it doesn't let me copy to clipboard anymore.

Sorry for my rough english, but my question is: How can i send an email to a 300 person list?
I am currently using "mailto" function that works with smaller lists.

thanks in advance hope i expressed correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emailing to multiple recipients with html Mailto: not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278363/emailing-to-multiple-recipients-with-html-mailto-not-working)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Code is: href='mailto:one@email.com;two@email.com;three@email.com' basically but i have a function that replaces the mails according to a filter